# Recursive data types in firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, types

I am using .bolt extension to describe firestore rules. I convert .bolt to .json after. I get ***TYPE_RECURSION*** error in firebase rules playground.

Example of .bolt type description:

Type OrderedList {
…
content: ListItem[]
}

Type BulletList {
…
content: ListItem[]
}

Type ListItem {
…
content: SomeTextNode[] | BulletList[] | OrderedList[]
}

If anyone had such issue before, please give me some hints

Comment: [Bolt](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/bolt) is a language for generating security rules for the Firebase Realtime Database, not for Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Do you know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Edit your question to fix the tags, show the exact error message you get, and (since this is in the rules playground) a screenshot of the context in which you get this error.